# How can I find useless divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find all useless nested HTML tags to merge them.

```
<div style="font-size:12px">   --> Goal  (this is useless)
   <div style="font-size:13px">   --> Not goal 
        blah blah
   </div>
</div>

<div style="font-size:12px">   --> Not goal 
    blah blah
    <div style="font-size:13px">   --> Not goal 
       blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, I want to find all tags with only one child and without any `<text>` node.

How can I find these?

Comment: So you current code is working?

Comment: What is the question and what are expected results?

Comment: Your title says *"only one HTML child tag"*, but based on your second example, are you saying that you don't want the `div` to be selected if it has a text node and an element node?

Comment: `I want to find all useless nested HTML tags` - What do you define useless? When it has only 1 child? When a div has no text? - The sample HTML is very small, might be good to see more `Goal` divs to see what you are looking for exactly? - `I use the below code do you have any better solution?` - So,..what's wrong with the current code? What is the expected and what is the actual result?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes that's it

Comment: @JoshCrozier  I edited my post.  Can you help me? Will my solution work anywhere?

Comment: You seem to confuse `class` attribute with `style` one... If you define relevant class for all targeted DIVs, it would be quite easy to filter them out

Comment: @A.Wolff I edited that I lost my mind  :'(

Comment: Your posted code missing more complex example but maybe this will fit all your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/byh5ve0m/   This one would handle case you wish to keep container if more than one child https://jsfiddle.net/byh5ve0m/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you very much, that's it what I'm wanted. I edited your sample (https://jsfiddle.net/sxawbw9L/) If you posted it I checked it as the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for a code review belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @A. Wolff answer seems to be perfect I put his answer for others:

```js
var singleChilds = $('div').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim()
  }).length && $(this).children().length < 2
});

console.log(singleChilds.attr('name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size:12px" name="Goal">
  <div style="font-size:13px">
    blah blah
  </div>
</div>

<div style="font-size:12px" name="notGoal">
  blah blah
  <div style="font-size:13px" name="notGoal">
    blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to @A. Wolff.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="goal" style="font-size: 12px">
        
        <div class="notgoal" style="font-size: 13px">
       --> Not goal 
        blah blah
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="notgoal" style="font-size: 12px">
        --> Not goal 
            blah blah
        <div class="notgoal" style="font-size: 13px">
            --> Not goal 
         blah blah
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var divs = [];
        $('div').each(function ()
        {
            var a = $(this);
            var childLenght = $(this).children().length;
            var textsEqual = $(this).children().eq(0).text().trim() == $(this).text().trim();
            if (childLenght === 1 && textsEqual)
            {
                divs.push($(this));
                console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            }
        });
        
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I think @A.Wolff Is perfect. ;)

Comment: Why you think that is a good answer? He separated the `divs` by class name container. It was very easy from first to do this!!

Comment: if you notice he didn't use the name as a selector and I added this names to be able to see his filter result.

Comment: Sharmandeh :( but i do not think so. Both of the codes start with `$('.container').filter` , If you remove class name `.container` from html, does it still works? Finally if i am wrong and that codes are good, Still i don't think my answer is deserve to downvote, because it gives the answer.

Comment: Doshmanet Sharmande ;) Yes it's work. check this please:
https://jsfiddle.net/2e1346u3/  . We can use $(document).find( "*" ) instead of $('div').

Comment: Yes it is true. But the links in comments was some thing else. But this one is good.